# Need a simple way to display text to screen on android during create() method on LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

My LibGDX game takes 5-10 seconds to load up because the create() method has to do a lot of things, loading up images and creating objects that are used in the game. I need to just display some simple text to the screen during that time, saying something like "Loading..." so that people know the game is working, but just to be patient. I'm using LibGDX to make my game, but of course the solution doesn't have to be using a method of LibGDX if that isn't simplest, it just has to work.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me a really simple way of doing this, or be really thorough. I have no experience coding and do not understand all the methods people have said that I have found during my research, so please keep the solution as simple as possible.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AssetManager` and load your assets asynchronously.

Here's a general structure for how it could be done.

```
private boolean loadComplete;
private AssetManager assetManager;

@Override
public void create(){
    //...
    assetManager = new AssetManager();
    assetManager.load(/*whatever*/);
    assetManager.load(/*whatever*/);
    assetManager.load(/*whatever*/);
    loadComplete = false;
}

private void onAssetsLoaded(){
    loadComplete = true;
    //abc = assetManager.get(...);
    //and so on
    // You can switch to any Screen
}

@Override
public void render(){
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //load one asset at a time per frame until loading is complete
    if (!assetManager.update()){
        //maybe draw a loading screen or you can leave the screen blank.
        return;
    }

    //get references to its assets or switch to other screen.
    if (!loadComplete)
        onAssetsLoaded();
}

@Override
public void dispose(){
  assetManager.dispose();
}
```